# Can we take the fees from seller and not buyer in 0x v4?

Tags: web3js, contract-design, nft, fees, 0x

In v4 it was introduced that fees are paid by the buyer, denominated in the asset paid by the buyer, and are paid in addition to the `erc20TokenAmount` specified in the order.

https://docs.0x.org/nft-support/guides/creating-orders/royalties-and-fees

I wish to incorporate a change here to deduct the fees from the seller's cut so that the buyer ends up paying exactly the amount for which the asset was listed (gasless transaction).
Is there any way to configure this with 0x without a lot of overhead? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what your use case is but this seems like an issue that is better solved in the display logic on the frontend.  There is nothing stopping you from calculating the total with gas included and showing that to the buyer as "exactly the amount paid(which is the cost of gas plus the cost and inherently taking the 'cut from the seller')".

Answer (score 0):

Current design of ZRX fees structure it will add the fee to the order, so if you want to remove the added fee you should deduct it from the total amount on the frontend, when the seller is building the order. Or make it clear for the buyer that he is paying an additional fee to the atual listed amount.

A strategy that I used on the marketplace that I am building is transparently say to buyer that he will pay an additional fee over the listed amount, a strategy used by the common marketplaces out there.

The reason to the buyer pay the fee is technical, the buyer already needs to approve the 0x contract to move the erc20 token amount, if it was to be deducted by the seller, the seller besides approve the NFT to be selled, needed as well to approve the erc20 token amount associated to the fee.